# Range.Resize not working

Tags: excel, vba

I'm baffled, I've read on multiple sites that this is valid code

```
ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2)
```

ws being my worksheet. But I cannot, for the life of me, get it to work. However, if I do this.

```
ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2).Select
```

It magically works. But I don't want the Range selected, only resized.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what result do you expect? do you need to merge ranges? `Range.Resize` doesn't somehow modify representation of range in the sheet, it just modify the _range variable_ in vba code. So `set rng=ws.Range("B6")` refers to cell `B6`, but `Set rng=ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2)` refers to `B6:C6`

Comment: Okay, that actually makes sense.

I'm just flustered as to why I can find multiple sites showing my first example as valid code ;-)

As for your question, yes, I was trying to expand B6 with an additional column :-)

Comment: Try this one: `ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2).Merge`. Let me know if it helps

Comment: It did indeed, that you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, `Range.Resize` doesn't somehow modify representation of range in the sheet, it just modify the *range variable* in vba code.

So `Set rng = ws.Range("B6")` refers to cell `B6`, but `Set rng = ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2)` refers to `B6:C6`

What you're looking for is merging cells like this:

```
ws.Range("B6").Resize(, 2).Merge
```